# How can I pass a multidimensional array as props in React?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

I need to pass an array of arrays to a child component in React 16.12. I prefer not a break the array into its elements (still arrays) in parent and pass it as a whole. But it seems that React converts the inner arrays into strings. **I use the following scenario to explain the case, this is not exactly what my app does**, there it goes:

1. This is the array which I want to be passed down to the child -> [[0, 0], [100, 0], [100, 100], [0, 100]]
2. This is what browser (firefox, chrome) returns when I log the child props -> [[0, 0], [100, 0], [100, 100], [0, 100]]

seems everything is alright ...

3. This is the code and the rendered result when I want to show props content on screen ->

```
    class Rectest extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
        render() {
            console.log(this.props)
            return (
                <div>
                    <h6>
                        {this.props.corners[0]}
                    </h6>
                    <h6>
                        {this.props.corners[1]}
                    </h6>
                    <h6>
                        {this.props.corners[2]}
                    </h6>
                    <h6>
                        {this.props.corners[3]}
                    </h6>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

log of props-> [[0, 127 ], ​​ [128, 0 ], ​​[4, 133 ], ​​[4, 127 ]]

What is rendered in h6 tags-> 0127 1280 4133 4127

looks the inner arrays are taken as string in render function ...

4. And when I use this code ->

```
    class Rectest extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
        render() {
            console.log(this.props)
            return (
                 <div>
                    <h6>
                        {this.props.corners[0][0]}
                    </h6>
                    <h6>
                        {this.props.corners[1]}
                    </h6>
                    <h6>
                        {this.props.corners[2]}
                    </h6>
                    <h6>
                        {this.props.corners[3]}
                    </h6>
                </div>
            )
        }

    }
```

I get a type error: TypeError: this.props.corners[0] is undefined

Finally, this is the child component in parent:

```
<Rectest corners={this.state.photoCorners}/>
```

and this.props.corners[0] seems to be an array, because this code:

```
console.log(Array.isArray(this.props.corners[0]))
```

returns true.

Comment: Okay, but why do you want to display array elements inside h6 tags?

Comment: @Baran Nazari what are you trying to do?. what's requirement

Comment: I don't want to show them! I wanted to make the case clear. @Ramesh

Comment: I wnat to draw a rectangle according to props. @Vahid Akhtar

Comment: But the probable solution will be much useful for me, than this case. As I mentioned, there are ways for breaking the array and send the inner parts separately. I just made this simple scenario to show the point and I hope it does not make more confusion :)

Comment: It looks like corners are not an Array of arrays based on the information you provided. If you want to be more strict with the type of properties you use, take a look at PropTypes https://en.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Rectest.propTypes = {
  corners: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.array)
}

Rectest.defaultProps = {
  corners:[],
}

This is also a good practice

Comment: @BaranNazari If you want to draw a rectangle, for a start you can just calculate the width and height based on the props you receive and proceed as you want.

Comment: @BaranNazari Did you try this `{this.props.corner[0] && this.props.corners[0][0]}`?

Comment: @Alexander Vidaurre Arroyo     Thank you, but it did not work, and I did not get the point as well :) Why did you expect it to work? I am confused.

Comment: @BaranNazari, because if `this.props.corner[0]` is undefined then `this.props.corner[0][0]` is not evaluated, therefore you wouldn't get a TypeError

Answer (score 0):

check my codepen - https://codepen.io/viciousandambitious/pen/VwYpBjr?editors=1111 - all seems fine with the code that you've provided. You're probably passing wrong values in props. Please make sure that you're passing an array.

```
class Rectest extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.corners[0])
        return (
            <div>
                <h6>
                    {this.props.corners[0][0]}
                </h6>
                <h6>
                   {this.props.corners[0][1]}
                </h6>
                <h6>
                    {this.props.corners[1][0]}
                </h6>
                <h6>
                    {this.props.corners[1][1]}
                </h6>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

React.render(<Rectest corners={[[123, 123], [234, 435]]}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Thank you @viciousP I saw your codepen, but my playground seems somehow working differently. I tried it your way as well.

Comment: @BaranNazari alright, can you explain the differences so we can come up with proper solution?

Comment: @ viciousP do you mean my environment?

Comment: @BaranNazari yes, as example that you've put in your questions seems to be working fine. I'm wondering what are the differences between that and your "real" example.

Comment: @viciousP I think he just wants to know why his array element is displayed as a string but not as it is displayed in the console(with the square brackets).

Comment: @viciousP I refactored the parent to send the array in separate props, so I m not stuck anymore:) But I think the environment should be the last suspect in such cases, am I wrong? I mean if this was the thing, we had have heard much more about noticing the environment when working with React. What's more, I can't dig into Codepen's environment. Am I wrong?

Comment: @BaranNazari So, I'm not sure whether I still understand your problem and question. Can you please specify it once again? Do you want to display all values of inner array inside h6 tag or what?